# Is there a way to use renderman in blender?

Tags: rendering, add-on, external-applications

The free version of renderman is coming out soon and I'm wondering if it can be pluged into blender. Is there a way to use renderman in blender?

Comment: [**This article might interest you**](http://blendertorenderman.blogspot.com/)

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?251446-PIXIE-2-2-5-3Delight-Exporter-%28Updated-For-2-66%29

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise maybe you can put an answer to this

Comment: @Chebhou I think the answer is no, the one solution was lacking in support. Is that what you were thinking?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise i just thought it would be better to write an answer to the question

Comment: @Chebhou Alright, I posted one

Answer (score 6):

Edited for 2022:

Pixar now offers full support for their own completely rewritten Blender plugin.

https://rmanwiki.pixar.com/display/RFB24/RenderMan+for+Blender+24.0

Answer (score 1):

#### This answer is now outdated as Renderman is now free and a plugin is available

---

This feature [**used to be supported**](http://blendertorenderman.blogspot.com/), however it now appears to have been discontinued due to a lack of interest of the Blender community. Now that Renderman is free, the developer might re-launch the addon if contacted and enough interest is shown, or another person could do somehting similar, and quite possibly have better success due to the growing interest. However, as of now, this capability is not supported.